# how to call an async function in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following function

```
func refresh () async {
}
```

how can I call refresh in viewWillAppear? Should I make viewWillAppear async too? If so how?

Comment: `Task { await refresh() }`? But I'd rather call a `Task.detached { await refresh() }` else you might see lags/UI freeze until the `refresh()` is complete, as `viewWillAppear()` should be called in main thread...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add `async` on `viewWillAppear` since it's an overrided function and doesn't support async. Just perform `refresh`:

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    Task.detached {
        await refresh()
    }
}
```

Comment: As Larme pointed out in their comment, `Task.detached` would be better so you don't block the main thread waiting for the refresh function to complete.

Comment: Logically you also need cancel async task in `viewWillDisappear`, created in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: It's not necessarily true that you need `detached`, if most of the work is done in that function then yes but if it only calls some other function using `await` that for examples performs a download then it isn't necessary to use `detached` since that other function will run on a background thread.

Comment: If there are no `detached`, even if you do, let's say a Web API call, wouldn't this wait until the "return" of the method (which might take time, even if most work is done on another thread)?