# Invalid conversion from 'async' function of type '(UIAlertAction)

Tags: ios, swift, async-await

I'm trying to convert my swift code to use async/await. I have the following code

```
 alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add to Library", style: .default) { _ in
      await Library.sharedInstance.add(book: self.book, vc: self)
      self.removeFromLibrary = !self.removeFromLibrary
 });
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error Invalid conversion from 'async' function of type '(UIAlertAction) async -> Void' to synchronous function type '(UIAlertAction) -> Void'

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't do `async` inside the closure of that `UIAlertAction`, because the closure isn't defined with an `async`. You might want to use Task { await Library... } to do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to call an async function in viewWillAppear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77866737/how-to-call-an-async-function-in-viewwillappear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialiser of `UIAlertAction` looks like this

```
convenience init(
    title: String?,
    style: UIAlertAction.Style,
    handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil
)
```

The handler is an optional wrapping `(UIAlertAction) -> Void` but your closure that you pass to it has an asynchronous call in it, so its type is `(UIAlertAction) async -> Void`. This means it has the wrong type and cannot be used in place of a synchronous function.

You'll need to wrap your `await` call in a `Task` e.g

```
Task
{
    await Library.sharedInstance.add(book: self.book, vc: self)
}
```

You'll probably want to put the

```
self.removeFromLibrary = !self.removeFromLibrary
```

in the task too, or you might have a race condition.